# Update max value from a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update a table's value using `max(col)` in a subquery, but for some reason, it's updating all values that match the `user_id` column I'm using.

This is my table structure:

```
user_id | steps | in_date
--------+-------+-----------
8       |10     | 1522246892
8       |10     | 1522250713
7       |10     | 1522250799
```

And this is my query:

```
UPDATE userdata
    SET steps = (steps + 20)
    WHERE user_id = 8
    AND in_date = (SELECT max(in_date) WHERE user_id = 8);
```

I expected it to update only the second column, but it instead updates both columns with `user_id` = 8. Why isn't it working as expected? What am I doing wrong?

*Edit:* Thanks to Manoj's comment, I changed the query to the following, and it works:

```
UPDATE userdata 
    SET steps = (steps + 20)
    WHERE user_id = 8
    ORDER BY in_date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Doing it his way is even better, since I don't have to run two queries, and already gets the highest one by id.

Comment: Make sure that your select is from the same table you are showing us.

Comment: @scaisEdge what do you mean by that?

Comment: is clear  to .me .. check for your actual real data content  .. and if you are in console or sql ide .. try disconnect  and reconnect

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci I just checked by your comment. I tried `WHERE userdata.user_id = 8`, but still same result. Didn't think about that possibility!

Comment: which data type is user_id ????

Comment: @scaisEdge It's an `int(11)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will encounter sql error "**You can't specify target table 'userdata' for update in FROM clause**" when you use same table in the sub-query to update the same table.

Its strange that you say its running because,
- you missed from clause in your sub-query
- you can't use same table

Can you please be more specific.

Comment: Exactly. This is why I'm using `userdata.user_id`. What do you mean by being more specific? I'll try to provide all info you need.

Comment: can u try this:
** UPDATE userdata
    SET steps = (steps + 20)
    WHERE user_id = 8
    order by in_date desc limit 1; **

Comment: Ohh, it works! That is much better, thank you! I didn't think about that.

Comment: Happy that helped you @Newbb and may others :)

Answer (score 0):

seems you missed  the from  clause in subselect  and for avoid conflit between select and updated  value you could build a temp table  using ainner subselect

```
UPDATE userdata
SET steps = (steps + 20)
WHERE user_id = 8
AND in_date = ( select max_date from (
          SELECT max(in_date) max_date FROM userdata  WHERE  user_id = 8) t);
```

and in this way  the AND clause could be always true

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not allowed in mysql. I'd either have to use `userdata.column`, or use an inner join. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause) is another question where they reply that. Thanks for the answer anyways!